# Xcode: unit tests are misbehaving

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, output

I'm working on an app for iOS. I have 3 targets:

- App — the app itself
- AppTests — unit tests
- AppUITests — UI tests

The third one is currently empty, but I intend to use it later. There are lots of tests in the second one.

Before yesterday, when I pressed Cmd+U, Xcode would happily run all tests for me (on a simulator, usually), and give me comprehensive report in the Debug area down below.

All of a sudden that changed. Now I see output from unit tests (AppTests) for less than a second, then it disappears, and a bit later the output from UI tests appears instead — which is completely useless, since there are no UI tests.

I'm not OK with this. UI tests sometimes print valuable information (not normally, but sometimes I use that). I need to see this output. And I kinda can: I see that it's still there in the log file, like `DerivedData/App/Logs/Test/<long-guid-here>/Session-2016-06-16_18\:34\:44-EjeDwZ.log`, along with lots and lots of other information that I don't understand. And there is another file, like `Session-2016-06-16_18:34:44-Wlv6KP.log`, in the same folder, with, as it seems, output from UI tests.

I want to see both, as it was before. I'm not OK with grepping through the giant log file.

What I tried:

- Removing DerivedData folder entirely.
- Cloning the same project from git into a new directory and starting it from there.
- Reverting to an earlier version of the code, which worked fine before.
- Removing `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.*`.
- Trying tests on a different simulator.

Doesn't matter.

Another symptom is that the "Tests" panel in Xcode doesn't work anymore. It still correctly displays test suites and tests themselves, but small buttons to the right of tests, intended to run them, don't do anything. I still can run the suite by right-clicking on it and choosing `Run AppTests` (and I see the output in that case), but not by clicking on buttons. Also, I can run individual tests by clicking on the buttons in the code editor, to the left of test functions.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix it?

Xcode 7.3, Swift, if it matters.

**Update:**
After fiddling with "Edit Scheme" — specifically, changing "Debug" to "Release", running tests, and then changing back — "Run" buttons in the Tests Navigator suddenly started working. Issue with two different logs still remains, and I have no idea what to make of this.

**Update 2:**
"Run" buttons stopped working AGAIN, for no obvious reason.

**Update 3:**
OK, I figured out how to view tests output in the report instead of debug area.

Comment: When you go to the tests target settings, does it still have the "host application" specified in the "general" tab?

Comment: The AppTests target has "Host Application" specified as "App", with checkbox "Allow testing Host Application APIs" enabled. The AppUITests target has "Target Application" setting instead, also set to "App"; no checkbox there.

Comment: Have you faced this issue after adding AppUITests or this target was there before?

Comment: This target was there from day 1. It wasn't touched for a long time, not sure if ever.

Comment: Without look at the project it is hard to say what's going on. But you can disable UI tests in scheme editor or reorder tests so that UI tests won't override output of Unit tests